# How to add image to array in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, image, insert

How to add image to array in laravel ?

I have code like this for insert data

```
$itemcodes = $request->itemcode;
foreach ($itemcodes as $i => $item_code) {
     $order_detail[] = [
       'warr_item_code'            => $item_code,
       'warr_item_category'        => $request->itemcategory[$i],
       'warr_item_name'            => $request->itemname[$i],
       'warr_item_qty'             => $request->itemqty[$i],
       'warr_item_condition'       => $request->itemcondition[$i],
       'warr_item_origin'          => $request->itemorigin[$i],
       'warr_item_purchase_year'   => $request->itempurchaseyear[$i],

       if ($request->hasfile($request->itemimg[$i])) {
           $file               = $request->file($request->itemimg[$i]),
           $extension          = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(),
           $img                = time() . '.' . $extension;
           $file->move('dist/images/data-barang/', $img);
           'warr_item_img'     => $img;
       } else {
           return $request;
           'warr_item_img'     => '';
       }
    ];
          
}
WarrentItemModel::insert($order_detail);
```

I know, if my code was wrong, but i so confused, how to add image to array ? i used laravel framework for insert data to database.

Comment: What error are you getting? If no error what is the issue? One issue which is visible is that you are instantiating `$order_detail` in the `foreach` loop while using it outside the loop at `WarrentItemModel::insert($order_detail)` where it may be undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($itemcodes as $i => $item_code) {
     $tmp = [
       'warr_item_code'            => $item_code,
       'warr_item_category'        => $request->itemcategory[$i],
       'warr_item_name'            => $request->itemname[$i],
       'warr_item_qty'             => $request->itemqty[$i],
       'warr_item_condition'       => $request->itemcondition[$i],
       'warr_item_origin'          => $request->itemorigin[$i],
       'warr_item_purchase_year'   => $request->itempurchaseyear[$i],
    ];

    if ($request->hasfile($request->itemimg[$i])) {
       $file               = $request->file($request->itemimg[$i]),
       $extension          = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(),
       $img                = time() . '.' . $extension;
       $file->move('dist/images/data-barang/', $img);
       $pathOfImage = 'dist/images/data-barang/' . $img;
       $tmp['warr_item_img']     = $pathOfImage ;
    } else {
       $tmp['warr_item_img']     = '';
    }
    $order_detail[] = $tmp   
}
```

**You should use [path](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#paths-method-list) instead of absolute path**